# CAST failed when using this to convert in UNION in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use `CAST` in order to concatenate with a unique identifier int data type.

When I run the script in a single select statement it works but when I run it together using union with another query I get the error message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '211870 1:2' to data type int.

See below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE  
       WHEN SHIFT_CODE = '1:2 Support' 
          THEN '3'
          ELSE '' 
    END [Datatype Id],
    CAST(SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' 1:2' [Unique Visit ID]
 '' [Date],
 '' [Start Time],
 ''+ ',' [End Time],
 ''+ ',,,' [Unique Client ID],
 '' [Client Forename]
FROM 
    Subshift
UNION

  SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST(CAST(EE.Start_Date_SK AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DATE) >= (GETDATE() - 41) 
          THEN ' 11 '
          ELSE ''
    END [DataTypeID],
    '' [Unique Visit ID],
    '' [Date],
    '' [Start Time],
    ''+ ',' [End Time],
    ''+ ',,,' [Unique Client ID],
    '' [Client Forename]
  FROM 
     Subshift
```

The result I get when I run it without using Union

```
DataTypeID  Unique Visit ID     Date        Start Time  End Time
    3         272574 1:2       20/01/2020   19:00       22:00,
    3         272575 1:2       23/01/2020   19:00       22:00,
    3         272575 1:2       23/01/2020   19:00       22:00,`
```

The result I get when using Union:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '211870 1:2' to data type int.

Can you please advise with a T-SQL query that would be the best to use for `CAST` and `CONVERT` function in `UNION`?

The second half of the union is below:

Comment: Where is the second half of the union?  The error is pretty clear: you have a text column which should be integer.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: The second half is posted above. I am using SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18206.0

Comment: yes, but what version of SQL? Not Management Studio

Comment: if you don't know how to check, run this in a new query `select @@version` then revert

Comment: the version is sql server 2018

Comment: There is no SQL of that version as far I'm aware @YemisiAdeoluwa

Comment: Secondly, the results from your first query have more columns than the query you provided? @YemisiAdeoluwa

Comment: v18.4    2019 is installed on my laptop

Comment: but i am connected to Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Dec  4 2019 21:24:18   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: they are the same column number i didnt just add it in the first one.

Comment: Any help please

Comment: @YemisiAdeoluwa Please provide the full query with the union that fails - maybe you're trying to insert into table, which has a second column as int type

Comment: please find it modified in the above query. thank you

Comment: This expression `CAST(CAST(EE.Start_Date_SK AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DATE) >= (GETDATE() - 41)` is really weird and it is likely the root of the problem. Try to comment it out and then, if the error is indeed due to it, use functions like `DATEADD` and/or `DATEDIFF`

Comment: @YemisiAdeoluwa I also edited my answer. You can try my advice. Your problem probably stems from here: https://blog.dbdigger.com/data-type-precedence-t-sql/ . If nothing else works, you might create two common table expressions (WITH queries) and union their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you're trying to insert your data into a table that is not properly structured (second column is of type int).

You can also try to cast the value a second time:

```
CAST(CAST(SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' 1:2' AS VARCHAR(24)) [Unique Visit ID]
```

Comment: sorry my fault, i just add it to the other union query and it worked thanks

Comment: @YemisiAdeoluwa If it did work, please mark my question as an answer (the tick mark)

Comment: may i use this oppurtunity to ask if you can help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59787550/12147513