# How do I put a condition in the select statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation

A carer can provide support to two different service at the same Start time and End time this is called 1:2 Service type. The unique ID for this type of shift type are generated as the same unique ID for this type of service. I want to add 2 at the end of the unique ID for every second service. How do I find this? Bare in mind I am using this within the UNION with other 3 select statement. The first query above the Union is the one

My query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE  
   WHEN SHIFT_CODE = '1:2 Support' 
      THEN '3'
      ELSE '' 
END [Datatype Id],
CAST(SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' 1:2' [Unique Visit ID]

'' [Date],
'' [Start Time],
''+ ',' [End Time],
''+ ',,,' [Unique Client ID],
'' [Client Forename]

    FROM 

  Subshift

  UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE 
     WHEN CAST(CAST(EE.Start_Date_SK AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DATE) >= (GETDATE() - 41) 
      THEN ' 11 '
      ELSE ''
  END [DataTypeID],
 '' [Unique Visit ID],
 '' [Date],
 '' [Start Time],
 ''+ ',' [End Time],
 ''+ ',,,' [Unique Client ID],
 '' [Client Forename]
   FROM 
      Subshift
```

Result I get is:

```
Service    Unique Visit ID  Carer           Date        Start Time   End Time    SHIFT_PROPERTY_CODE
 Moira      211870 2          A         16/12/2019        19:00        22:00,      1:2 Support
 Marta      211870 2          A         16/12/2019        19:00        22:00,      1:2 Support
 Rebecca    211871 2          B         19/12/2019        19:00        22:00,      1:2 Support
 Elsie      211871 2          B         19/12/2019        19:00        22:00,      1:2 Support
```

Desired Result should be:

`Service Unique Visit ID Carer  Date      Start Time End Time SHIFT_PROPERTY_CODE
 Moira    211870          A    16/12/2019 19:00      22:00,    1:2 Support
 Marta    211870 2        A    16/12/2019 19:00      22:00,    1:2 Support
 Rebecca  211871          B    19/12/2019 19:00      22:00,    1:2 Support
 Elsie    211871 2        B    19/12/2019 19:00      22:00,    1:2 Support`

Comment: is anyone able to help with this thanks

Comment: please can some one help  me with to solve this. Suggestion would be much appreciated as I need it to progress to the final stage of the project i am currently working on

Comment: Does the order matter? You can use Row_number() function if you can get a suitable way to order ALL rows

Comment: Yes the order matter.

Comment: are you aware of the fact that you can use IF/ELSE? maybe it is not a clean solution but it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something along these lines:

```
SELECT 
  Case Row_Number() OVER (Partition By SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID Order By ClientName) 
   when 1 then S.Schedule_Subshift_ID
   when 2 then S.Schedule_Subshift_ID + ' 2'
   end
FROM Subshift
```

You can partition by service id and order by time for example, I don't exactly understand your case. Please keep in mind that the Query you copied DOES NOT result in the result sets below. So if you want me to be more specific - please provide the proper query.

Comment: I am sorry but the query above is the query i am using. Also i have implemented your suggestion , almost there but the only issue is that it is substituting all the values of SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID with 2 and the other values in the same column  with blank or NULL. I would like it to show all the SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID + '  2'  (concatenate with 2) example:       SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID                                                                                                          56488855      5648855  2  just like the desired result. thank you

Comment: Hi @GeorgiG are you still able to help me please?

Comment: @YemisiAdeoluwa I changed my answer and you might find it useful. The first column in your query is named Datatype Id. The first column in the example results is Service. They don't match, so the query must be different.

Comment: I will try it again tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you so much for your help. much appreciated

Comment: it worked i can see the SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID but unfortunately, i cannot see 2 at the end of the ID.I think the issue is with this line:  when 2 then SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID + ' 2'                 I changed it to:  when 2 then CAST(CAST(SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '  2' AS VARCHAR(24)) but getting this error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 175
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '211870  2' to data type int.

Comment: thank you very much for all your help. i realised that i had not add CAST(CAST(SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID AS VARCHAR(20))  to the below:    when 1 then CAST(SS.Schedule_Subshift_ID AS VARCHAR(20))  and also to the first line in the case statement. this solved it. Thank you very much